# Is there a way in Android to tell if a users device has an actual keyboard or not?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I would like to detect if the current users phone has a hardware keyboard or only a on-screen keyboard. Is this possible with the SDK?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes, you can**.

Fetch the [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) object using

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
```

...and then look at the [`keyboard`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboard) field.

If they value of [`keyboard`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboard) is not [KEYBOARD_NOKEYS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#KEYBOARD_NOKEYS), the user has a hardware keyboard.

Note that as [@Carl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/928054/carl) says in his comment below, the user may attach a USB keyboard at any point while your app is running, causing the value of `keyboard` to change.

Comment: While it is true that the user DOES have a hardware keyboard if config.keyboard is NOT KEYBOARD_NOKEYS, it should be noted that a device may report KEYBOARD_NOKEYS, but then have an external USB keyboard attached to it and report KEYBOARD_QWERTY, all while your app is running.  At least, I have a GTablet running CyanogenMod 7.0.3-Harmony / Android 2.3.3 that does exactly that.

And also, it is possible that the value of keyboard, when not KEYBOARD_NOKEYS, is KEYBOARD_12KEY, rather than KEYBOARD_QWERTY, so if the type of keyboard is important to you, you may want to test for these specifically.

Comment: @Carl - updated to include the point re: keyboards being attached mid-execution of the app. Thanks.